# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory - code worked on new computer doesnt work on old one

Tags: python, ffmpeg, operating-system, errno

I wrote a script to extract frames from a database I have stored on my computer desktop.  I wrote the code on a different computer (new macbook pro 2016) as my computer's harddrive died.  I was finally able to restore my computer (and therefore returned the new computer I wrote the code on).

I am trying to run the same script, completely unchanged and I keep getting this error: (The line btwn ** ATTENTION** is the printed command line.)

```
--------------------------**********ATTENTION**********-------------------------
ffmpeg -i /Desktop/UCF101/v_BaseballPitch_g01_c01.avi -ss 00:00:00.0 -vframes 1 BPout0.png
--------------------------**********ATTENTION**********-------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Desktop/processing.py", line 50, in <module>
    processvideo('/Desktop/UCF101/v_BaseballPitch_g01_c01.avi')
  File "./Desktop/processing.py", line 47, in processvideo
    sp.check_output(args) #was cmdline
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Everything is in the same place as it was on the new computer where it was able to run successfully.  Does anyone have any idea what it could be? Could my version of python have anything to do with it? Could it be a larger issue on my computer? Any tips for debugging whats caused this error? I've already printed the command (matches perfectly), used shlex.split("mycommandline"), checked my current directory in the script...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm interpreting the question correctly, but I think you're passing a path to a script in some way (maybe hardcoded, maybe as a commmand line parameter, maybe in a config file), and that path is getting to the ATTENTION line.

In the ATTENTION line, shouldn't the path be `~/Desktop/path/to/file` instead of `/Desktop/path/to/file`? If it is, that would explain why your application can't find the file.